# is it possible edit prefix list using netconf

Tags: juniper-junos, netconf

Is it possible to edit the prefix list through netconf in juniper router.

I am using new version of juniper router.

Comment: Please can you add some more detail. What version of Junos are you running? Are you using the Junos specific YANG modules or generic ones like OpenConfig? Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: junos version :  15.1f5, Device : juniper mx240, And i am using pyez on top of netconf to automate.

Comment: Ah. then I suggest you RTFM on the PyEz github page, it says: SUPPORT >  For questions and general support, please visit our Google Group > You can also post your query on stackoverflow with pyez tag :)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N.B: Please see my comments above.

As per the Junos documentation (https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos13.3/topics/reference/tag-summary/netconf-junos-xml-protocol-load-configuration.html) you can use the `<configuration-set>` RPC to pass standard CLI configuration statements.

So for your question of "Is it possible to edit the prefix list through NETCONF in juniper router" the answer is "yes" but I expect that was not quite what you were looking for. I expect you wanted to know if there was a specific RPC for this. I don't know the answer to that question. Look through the Junos YANG modules, they have a very high coverage rate (can't find exact figure right now but it's something like 90% of the CLI via the XML RPC).

Junos stores configuration in its internal back-end database. When a new CLI configuration option is added the database is edited to support this, then an XML RPC in implemented, then finally the CLI command is added. Most CLI commands are translated to the XML RPC internally when working on the CLI and then formatted into the backend config database, so unless you are doing something quite unusual there is a very high chance this is covered by the XML RPC without using the `<configuration-set>` call, because XML RPCs are reated to underpin the CLI command.